# AJAX sending wrong info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so i have 3 radios buttons 
with different values, when i select one of them it always giving me the value "3" or the last value of them.I tried submit with no ajax it's work fine !

HERE IS MY .js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
     url = that.attr('action'),
     type = that.attr('method') ,
     data  = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();


        data[name] = value;
    });

        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data, 
        success : function(rdata) {
              $("#st").html(rdata);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

AND here is my html :

```
<form action="test.php" id="send" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off">
 <table>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="val" value="1">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="val" value="2">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="val" value="3">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr><tr><td><div id='st'></div>/td></tr>         

</table>
```

test.php  :

```
if (isset($_POST['val'])) {
   $val = $_POST['val'];
   echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply correct the problem, you should change the following line as follows:

```
..    
that.find('[name]:checked').each(function(index, value){
..
```

What you were doing there, is iterating through all of the radio buttons, and always assigning the value to your variable, regardless the radio button's checked status. With the `:checked` modifier, you are telling it to only look at elements that are checked (and actually, the  `.each` isn't quite necessary either in this case). You could modify it like this (as you will normally have only one radio checked), replace the `.each` iteration with following:

```
checkedRadio = that.find('[name]:checked');
name = checkedRadio.attr('name');
value = checkedRadio.val();

data[name] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following snippet to get the selected radiobutton value
Now you are iterating over all radiobuttons and sending the data for the value of the button (so always the last in the each() is send).

```
$('input[name=val]:checked').val()
```

I have updated the answer with your code filled in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
     url = that.attr('action'),
     type = that.attr('method') ,
     data  = {};

    data[name] = $('input[name=val]:checked').val();

        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data, 
        success : function(rdata) {
              $("#st").html(rdata);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: he was actually retrieving the name `attribute` into a `variable` called name. Your code right now will stop, as no variable named `name` is currently defined. See my answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Working Demo : **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8v7zqgu/)** - `You can check console network it is sending the data.`

You want to get the value of radio button which is checked so you can use `$('input[name=val]:checked').val()`

try like this :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('form').on('submit', function() {
      var that = $(this),
      url = that.attr('action'),
      type = that.attr('method') ,
      data  = {};

      //data[name] = $('input[name=val]:checked').val();

        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: type,
           data: 'val = '+$('input[name=val]:checked').val();, 
           success : function(rdata) {
              $("#st").html(rdata);
           }
       });

      return false;
   });
 });
```

You can then get the value on your test.php file like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['val'])) {
   $val = $_POST['val'];
   echo $val;
}
```